# How to sign iOS project with two or more different accounts keeping only one project

Tags: ios, xcode

I've recently got an iOS app template with a friend. We want to keep only one code in our bitbucket but we want to create the best structure to sign it with our different Apple Developer Account and also have our own icons, characters , images in general. You can check our iOS template [here](http://www.buyioscode.com/products/flappy-pig). It's a native project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily using different Targets in `Xcode`.

You can define different icon, characters, images, etc. for each target and you will get different apps from the same `Xcode` project.

Check out [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html) from Apple Developer documentation.